# How to differentiate between XMLDocument.documentElement and HTMLDocument.documentElement in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, typescript

In my code I'm parsing a few html strings and xml strings in order to manipulate their DOM.

Before I'm parsing them, I differentiate between the types of the strings by searching for an `<?xml ... ?>` tag in the beginning of them, so I know if I should parse them using `parseAsHTML` or `$.parseXML` functions. In order to manipulate their DOM tree, I am forwarding to the next functions (which manipulates them) their `documentElement` attributes (or "body" in the case of html strings, which gives the same). Here comes the problem.

It seems that for both `HTMLDocument` objects and `XMLDocument` objects the `documentElement` is instance of the type `HTMLElement`. Farthermore, the `documentElement` does not have the `<?xml ... ?>` tag in its DOM tree, even though it came from an xml string. That means that if I need to check later what type of DOM tree I have, I won't be able to do so because all my trees are from the type of `HTMLElement`. The html trees are also not full trees so i can't search for  tags or something like that.

I know I can just pass the `Document`objects themselves, but it will make me change tens of functions that already gets `Element` so I would not like to do so. So my question is how can I distinguish between the elements? Or is there a way to make some kind of `XMLEntity` that will have of the `HTMLEntity` properties out of `XMLDocument` so I'll be able to make the difference?

Thanks for the help!

If anything is not clear, you are free to ask and I'll try to explain the situation better.

Comment: Are you getting this xml/html from a webservice?

Comment: I'm getting it as a string, does it matter how?

Comment: Kind of. If it's off of a webservice, you could potentially add a header to your response that says if it's xml or html, like it's Content-Type for example. That way you can know without having to pollute your data.

Comment: So the answer is no, I'm getting it as a literal string.

Comment: You can't control what you are getting as this string? Is it from a third party source?

Comment: Yes, this is from a third party source. This is the reason I need to determine in the first place what kind of parsing I need to do.